# Graph challenge: Get adjacency list from list of children nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph, adjacency-list

I have a graph which has the following structure:

```
{'a':['b','c','d','e'],
'b':['d'],
'c':['d','e'],
'd':[],
'e':[],
'f':['i','j','c','e','d'],
'i':['c','e','d']
'j':['e']}
```

This list is not an adjacency list as it contains all the children of a node. Not the direct children.

the graph is supposed to look like this:

```
        a       f     
       / \     / \
      b   \   i   j
       \   \ /   /    
        \   c   /
         \ / \ /
          d   e
```

So the adjacecy list would look like:

```
{'a':['b','c'],
'b':['d'],
'c':['d','e'],
'd':[],
'e':[],
'f':['i','j'],
'i':['c'],
'j':['e']}
```

I need an algorithm to do this. The algorithm should be as fast as can be using minimum extra space. Anybody who can solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: A recursive algorithm to do this would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The question, in it's current form, is off-topic for this site.  Voting to close.

Comment: Is it assumed to be undirected and acyclic? Also, it would help if you posted your attempt, so that we could show you how to fix it. We're not here simply to do your homework for you

Comment: Yes. It is undirected and acyclic.

Comment: If it's undirected, why can't I get to `i` from `a`?

Comment: @ooga: I think the dict lists them in some order of traversal

Comment: @devnull M sorry if it seems off-topic. I hope i got the question across though. My attempts at this have been expensive in terms of space and time. I am looking for an efficient solution. Thanks.

Comment: My mistake. This is parent child relationship. The adjacency list would contain the direct children of a node. By this analogy, it is a directed graph since parent child relationship is one way.

Comment: @akshitBhatia: `My attempts at this have been expensive in terms of space and time`. Show us your attempts and we can try to help you fix them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite recursive, but you could iterate through each child, look it up, and remove all of its children from the current node:

```
def get_adjacency(graph):
    graph = {node: set(children) for node, children in graph.items()}

    for node, children in graph.items():
        for child in children:
            children = children - graph[child]
        graph[node] = children

    return {node: list(children) for node, children in graph.items()}

c = {
    'a': ['b','c','d','e'],
    'b': ['d'],
    'c': ['d','e'],
    'd': [],
    'e': [],
    'f': ['i','j','c','e','d'],
    'i': ['c','e','d'],
    'j': ['e']
}

print get_adjacency(c)
```